# Help prove a theorem about "generating a topology" in Engelking's General Topology.

Tags: general-topology

The following is taken from Engelking's General Topology.

BP1:For each $x\in X$, $B(x)\neq\emptyset$ and for each $U\in B(x),x\in U$.

BP2:If $x\in U\in B(y)$ then there exists $V\in B(x)$ such that $V\subseteq U$.

BP3:For any $U_1,U_2\in B(x),$ there exists $U\in B(x)$ such that $U\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$.

Theorem: Suppose we are given a set $X$ and a collection $\mathcal{B}$=$(B(x))_{x\in X}$ of families of subsets of $X$ that satisfies BP1, BP2 and BP3. Let $\tau$ be the family of all subsets of $X$ that are unions of subfamilies of $\bigcup_{x\in X}B(x)$. Then $\tau $ is a topology on $X$ and  $(B(x))_{x\in X}$ is a neighborhood system for $(X,\tau)$.

Proof (my try):

$U\in\tau$ iff $U=\bigcup_{s\in S}B(s)$ where $(B(s))_{s\in S}$ is a sub-family in $\mathcal{B}$. Then $\emptyset, X\in \tau$. Let $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\in \tau$. Then for each $\lambda\in\Lambda,$ $U_\lambda=\bigcup_{s\in S_\lambda}B(s)$ where $(B(s))_{s\in S_\lambda}$ is a sub-family in $\mathcal{B}$. Now $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda=\bigcup_{s\in T}B(s)$ where $T=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}S_\lambda$. Therefore $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda\in\tau$.

Are the above arguments alright? I failed to show that $\tau$ is closed under finite intersections. Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $X \in \tau$ follows from BP1: for every $x \in X$ we pick some $U_x \in B(x)$, and we know $x \in U_x$, both by BP1. Then $X =\cup\{U_x: x \in X\} \in \tau$.

Suppose $U,V$ are in $\tau$. Let $x \in U \cap V$. Then $x \in U_1 \in B(p_1); U_1 \subseteq U$, for some $p_1 \in X$, and $x \in V_1 \in B(p_2); V_1 \subseteq V$, for some $p_2 \in X$, as $U$ and $V$ are unions of such sets.
Now we apply the coherence property BP2, and find $U_x \in B(x)$ and $V_x \in B(x)$ such that $U_x \subseteq U_1$ and $V_x \subseteq V_1$.

Now apply BP3 to see that we have $W_x \in B(x)$ such that $W_x \subseteq U_x \cap V_x$, then $W_x \subseteq U_1 \cap V_1 \subseteq U \cap V$.

So in summary: $$\forall x \in U \cap V: \exists W_x \in B(x):W_x \subseteq U \cap V$$ and now it's easy to see that $U \cap V = \cup\{W_x: x \in U \cap V\} \in \tau$ as well. As we have intersections of 2 sets in the topology , by induction we get finitely many (standard argument).

So $\tau$ is indeed a topology and it's not too hard to see that $$O \in \tau \leftrightarrow \forall x \in O: \exists B \in B_x: B \subseteq O$$
which should look pretty familiar (and is just a minor reformulation of the definition, using BP2 as in the intersection proof). BP2 then says that all members of all $B(x)$ are open, and the last alternate formulation of openness states that all $B(x)$ form a local base for this topology. So we're done.